# Upgrading a Specialized Sirrus 2015?

Tags: shimano

Not having biked since I was a kid I went ahead and bought a Sirrus 2015 (the base model) for commuting 2x a week (~100 km weekly total) with a view to do 3-5 days. I've done about 1000km on it so far. I'm a fairly heavy guy at (210 lbs but fit from running/lifting) and commute with a backpack. I like the frame, seat and flat bar, but the shifting is slow and imprecise, and I've had it back to the shop a few times now for clunking and clicking in the bottom bracket/crank area. This issue just recently seemed to reoccur. So I'm concerned for the longevity and quality of those components. I've broken the stock pedals too.

Should I be upgrading my components? (I would be willing to shell out about $500 or so) What should I target for the budget?

Comment: The issues you're having can most likely be fixed. If you're polite and persistent, the store where you bought the bike should be able to fix them for free (since it's still a new bike).  Also get some better pedals (metal platform pedals can be very cheap).  Then ride this bike for 2 years and learn more about what you need/want in a bike. Then in 2 years, you can buy yourself a better bike. You will have more knowledge and experience at that time to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, my friend just bought that bike new and ended up taking it back and getting a similar priced Cannondale, mainly because it came with a Shimano 105 group set. I would look at that as a major upgrade especially if you are experiencing poor shifting. If you have 500 to spend you could probably get an Ultegra group as an even better upgrade and have a really nice performing bike on your hands, as well as lighter. I'm not partial to Shimano so I'd probably check out Sram as well, Rival will be in your price range.

A new wheel set would be the other major upgrade you could make for 500. There are a ton out there at that price but if shifting is what's bothering you I'd get that taken care of first.

Comment: I agree with @Batman as well, thats it's not worth sinking more money into a Sirrus, but since you asked specifically about upgrades, the ones above are viable.

Comment: OP wrote he has the base model Sirrus ($520). No similarly priced bike is going to have Shimano 105 parts.

Comment: I also agree, but I would advice you to go for the 105 group and upgrade the wheels instead of going for the ultegra. Shimano's 105 is extremely good value for money and that new set of wheels will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Putting 500 dollars into a Specialized Sirrus is insane, unless you have one of the top end ones which are well over 1000 dollars.

I'd say that you need a different bike shop to tune it up -- 210 lbs should not be a problem on a hybrid like the Sirrus, and all of them from the Sport Disc upward are spec'd with decent components for commuting. If you were to be willing to spend 500 dollars though, I'd sell the Sirrus and get something else.

Also read [this](http://sheldonbrown.com/creaks.html) on troubleshooting bike noises -- since a bike is made out of tubes, its pretty hard actually to figure out where exactly a noise is coming from.